# setonclicklistener and setontouchlistener at one time in android

Tags: android

i am new to android and having a requirement that setonclicklistener and setonTouchlistener both work at one time.i m performing some operation on the adapter side where i m having the imageview.some code to understand

adapter class:

```
public class Taukygridview extends BaseAdapter{

holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

//some click operation here
});

holder.imageview.setonTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());

holder.imageview.setonTouchListener(new MyDragListener());

}
```

here is the MyTouchListener class description:

```
public class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener
{
    private Context mcontext;
    public static int view_position=0;
    public static View first_image_view;

@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//some touch operation here
}
}
```

here is some description on the drag operation..

```
public class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener
{
@Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
   switch(v.getId):
{
  //some drag operation here

}
}
```

so while running the app only the touch operation work and if the touch operation return false then only the click operation work but can't omit or comprise any of the operation(actually i m performing click for selection and touch for the drag and drop operation).so can any one suggest me how can do all the operation without disabling any of the operation mention above.any reply will be very helpfull.thanks

Comment: write code for both and check in click event if touch return value is false then code of click listener should be execute

Comment: Doesn't calling setonTouchListener() twice overrides the first listener .. MyTouchListener ?

Answer (score 3):

As you can see, `public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)` returns a boolean

Set it to true (`return true;`) and it will consume the event so the `OnClickListener` will not be triggered.

Set it to false (`return false;`) and releasing the screen will trigger the `OnClickListener`

BTW not leading to any obscure bugs !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

When you're working with touch events, you're essentially overriding the built-in gesture detection (which handles click/long click/etc). While it *is* doable, I'd advise against it, since it has the potential of leading to really obscure bugs.

Instead, use [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) with a [SimpleGestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) and handle `onTapUpConfirmed` and `onScroll`.